# Loading an external .htm with javascript into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load an external .htm file to a div on my main page, and I have used the following code:

```
<a href="#file.htm" onclick="$('#content').load('file.htm')">Link</a>
```

It works in firefox, but not in chrome and IE. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 3):

Why not

**html**

```
<a href="file.htm" class="ajax">Link</a>
```

and add a **script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.ajax').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content').load( this.href );
    });
});
</script>
```

this way you can set a class `ajax` to all the links that load inside the `#content` area and it handle all of them..

---

Could it be that the reason it does not work is that you click too soon and the jquery is not yet loaded ?