# Loading an external .htm file to a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, load, external

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loading an external .htm with javascript into a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278078/loading-an-external-htm-with-javascript-into-a-div)
>   [Loading an external .htm file into a div with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280816/loading-an-external-htm-file-into-a-div-with-javascript)

This is my entire code:

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.ajax') .click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        $('#content').load( 'file.htm' )
    })
})
</script>

<div id="content">
    <p>random text</p>
</div>

<div><a href="#" class="ajax">Link</a></div>


</body>

</html>
```

The code works fine for loading an external file into a div in firefox, but nothing happens in chrome and IE, when I click the link. any advice ?

Comment: the `<head>` tag is missing a `>`, is this a copy paste error or is your original source like that?

Comment: It's normal to put the jquery script tag inside the head element. I'm not sure the 'document load' functionality will work properly if you don't.

Comment: Is `file.htm` on the same domain? Are you running locally? Chrome is pretty strict about XSS for local files.

Comment: yea, i'm running locally .. how should I solve the problem then?

Comment: your file named `.htm` and not `html`? also try `$('#content').load( 'file.htm body' )`

Comment: "_How should I solve the problem then?_" - stop running locally! Chrome does not allow files on the `file://` protocol to read each other. Either run a local server, or upload the files to the web.

Comment: right, thank you! :) could that be the cause of the IE-problems as well?

Comment: **Don't ask the [same](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11280816/102441) question [three times](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11278078/102441)**

Answer (score 0):

While it's not the cause of the problem, it's good practice to use semicolons:

```
$(function(){
    $('.ajax') .click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content').load( 'file.htm' );
    });
});
```

You'll occasionally hit some strange errors if you don't.